# How to require a built file using browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify

Hello browserify lords :)

I built a js library using browserify. Working well in the browser and everything looks great if I put it as a separate file in my html:

```
<!-- my library -->
<script src="./library/index.js"></script>

<!-- my app that uses the library -->
<script src="./app/build.js"></script>
```

But when I want to require the library file in my app, browserify complains.
Because the `require`s are still in the file and if I re-bundle it, browserify wants to re-include the files that are already included.

My files:

```
- library
  - src
    - core.js
    - foo.js
  - build.js
- app
  - src
    - core.js
  - build.js
```

library/src/foo.js:

```
module.exports = 'foo';
```

library/src/core.js:

```
console.log(require('./foo'));
```

app/src/core.js:

```
require('../../library/build');
```

`library/build.js` is created using browserify:

```
$ browserify library/src/core.js > library/build.js
```

**Now I want to build `app/src/core.js` the same way (`$ browserify app/src/core.js > app/build.js`) but it complains: `Error: Cannot find module './foo' from '/library'`**

I created a test repo to demo the issue: https://github.com/saeedseyfi/browserify-issue-1773

Please advise.